# How can I include a date (mm/dd/yyyy) in a web form using ASP.NET framework?

Tags: asp.net, date, webforms, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 and I want to add a date input type in my web form using ASP.NET framework but the problem is though ASP.NET has a Calendar method (`<asp:Calendar></asp:Calendar>`) so that it shows a large calendar but my target to add an input field for my web form.

I tried to solve this problem. This is what I tried:

[image]

This is what actually resulted:

[image]

But my output should be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you drop in a plane jane text box control, and set the textmode to date, say like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="200px" TextMode="Date">

</asp:TextBox>
```

[image]

And if you click on the calendar, you get this:

[image]

So, you really don't need a calendar control - and the above automatic pops on top of everything else - and it also don't take any code or anything at all on your part - just set the text mode of the text box to date